# join arrays and find matches

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, match, matching

So i'm working on a project and i've hit a bit of a roadblock. i'm trying to compare two arrays that've been populated with read-in and split text files, find the matches of individual elements (names), then populate a listbox with the resulting matches. here's the code i have so far:

```
Dim sr As IO.StreamReader
Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter
Dim guest As String()
Dim gift As String()

Private Sub frmTYC_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strFile1 As String
    Dim strFile2 As String
    Dim intCount As Integer

    strFile1 = "Guests.txt"
    strFile2 = "Gifts.txt"

    intCount = 0
    sr = IO.File.OpenText(strFile1)
    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        guest = sr.ReadLine.Split(",")
        lstGuests.Items.Add(guest(0))
        intCount += 1
    Loop
    sr.Close()

    intCount = 0
    sr = IO.File.OpenText(strFile2)
    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        gift = sr.ReadLine.Split(",")
        lstGifts.Items.Add(gift(1) & " " & "gifted" & " " & gift(0))
        intCount += 1
    Loop
    sr.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnList_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnList.Click

End Sub
```

i'm trying to compare guest(0) and gift(1) as those are the names, with guest having all the names and gift having all the names of the people in guest who gave a gift. i need the listbox to be populated on the list button click

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I think you should add the input text here as well. Whats `gift(1) & " " & "gifted" & " " & gift(0)` is gift(1) a name of guest? Whats the relation?